# Idiomatic way of performing serverside form validation of VueJS components in Laravel framework?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm new to Laravel and VueJS.  I built an HTML form with VueJS and was able to submit a payload to a Laravel controller and get back the appropriate validation errors in the form of a JSON object.  I will show my general approach below but wanted to know if what I did is considered the idiomatic Laravel+VueJS way?

I have a Laravel route and controller like this:

```
Route::post('/appetizer', 'AppetizerController@store')->name('appetizer.store');

class AppetizerController extends Controller {
   public function store (Request $request) {
     $request->validate([
        "name"=>"required",
        "calories"=>"required"
     ]);
     // Process Credit Card
     // ... ... etc ... ...

     if(!$process_credit_card_success) {
        return response()->json(["errors"=>["credit_card"=>$errors_from_capital_funds_management]]);
     }
   }
}
```

I made an HTML form that is completely VueJS.   I added a submit event which makes an axio calls like this:

```
window.axios.post("/appetizer",{
        "name":"Salad"
    }).then(response=>{
        console.log("success",response);
    }).catch(response=>{

        console.log("catch",response.response.data.errors);

        // Update the state/properties of my VueJS components based on response.response.data.errors
});
```

I deliberately submitted a payload with form errors to the controller and successfully got a `422 unprocessable entity` response back in my `catch block`.  The `response.response.data.errors` property contains all the validation messages.  Hence I will work directly with `response.response.data.errors` to get my error messages.

Is this the right way?  Should I be looking directly at the `response.response.data.errors` instead of some other abstraction for error messages?

Comment: Can't speak to the vue.js portion which is what I think you mainly are concerned with but I think idiomatic laravel side would be to use Form Request Validation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation